# Java Swing mouseClick not working

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

I'm trying to get some code to run on Mouse clicks using the MouseListener.

My code is as follows:

```
class TestingLayout extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener{
...
  private JFrame w = new JFrame();
  private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2),false);

  public TestingLayout(){
    addMouseListener(this);
    BoxLayout boxLayout = new BoxLayout(w.getContentPane(),BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    w.setLayout(boxLayout);
    w.add(panel1);
    w.setSize(800,600);
    w.setVisible(true);
    ...
  }
  ...
  @Override
  public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
    System.out.println("eh");
  }
}
```

But when I click on the JFrame, it doesn't run my code.
I can't seem to figure it out. One StackOverflow question references a MouseListener reference page that is no longer in existence unfortunately.

All help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [`setFocusable(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFocusable(boolean)) ?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Likely other components in the frame are consuming the events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of possible problems:

1. You are adding the listener to the frame, so maybe another component (like a panel) added to the frame is getting the event
2. A `mouseClick` is a combination of `mousePressed` and `mouseReleased`. If the mouse moves even a pixel between the two events an event will not be generated. Try listening for mousePressed.

If you need more help then post a proper [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem. In the future an `MCVE` should be posted with every question so we don't have to guess what you may or may not be doing.

Comment: Ah! It was the panel! I needed to do: panel1.addMouseListener(this); Thanks!

Comment: @DaveLass  `Is this code better?` - It is not an "MCVE". How is that code complete? We can't compile it. `Ah! It was the panel!` - glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Sorry. Thought that was enough to compile. So do I need a different mouselistener for each component?